# Hugo color theme not changing [params.palette]

Tags: docker, web, static, themes, hugo

I want to switch the theme color to blue, red or yellow, but it just doesn't work. the default is green color theme.

```
[params.palette]
    primary = "red" //I do change this to blue, yellow or green.
    accent  = "teal"
```

https://github.com/digitalcraftsman/hugo-material-docs/blob/master/exampleSite/config.toml

what could be the issue?

Comment: How do you run the server? Are you running `hugo server` within the `exampleSite` directory?

Comment: running it locally `hugo server` has no issue, the color is changing. But when I build a docker image of `exampleSite`, it just doesn't work when I tried to deploy it.

Sorry I forgot to put to mention on my first post that I was trying to build a docker image of hugo.

Comment: Docker and Hugo are 2 separate things that serve very different tasks. This isn't a hugo problem, it's a docker problem. As you have provided no docker related resources. I can only assume that you are not rebuilding your container and/or rerunning `hugo` after making the change Guesswork though. Vote to close until edited.